# Update gsheets formula range with google script

Tags: google-apps-script

This was originally posted on google product forums, but haven't gotten much traction there. I'm trying to find a script (or formula method, if it's possible) that can update a formula range either via some action or perhaps a button press.

I've created a spreadsheet to illustrate [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-dTI4RRLJZ7kQXy_FglszKVktRjV_pL6Gita6oAtof8/edit#gid=353873048).

In this sheet, I have a query formula in the `report tab`, cell `C3`, as follows:

```
=query({'20Feb'!$A:$C;'21Feb'!$A:$C},"select Col3 where Col2 = '" & $B3 & "' ",0)
```

I would like to update the following:

```
'20Feb'!$A:$C;'21Feb'!$A:$C
```

Either by script or by some set of formulas (I've tried indirect with no success, doesn't like multiple tabs).

The idea here is that I could add new tabs with dated ranges, and then press a button to run a script which updates it to include the new tab for reporting purposes. The output would then be:

```
=query({'19Feb'!$A:$C;'20Feb'!$A:$C;'21Feb'!$A:$C},"select Col3 where Col2 = '" & $B3 & "' ",0)
```

In a perfect world I could feed the script with a cell input, such that a separate tab for "script update" might have a place where I can write out the new range in full `'19Feb'!$A:$C;'20Feb'!$A:$C;'21Feb'!$A:$C`, stick that in `A1`, and tell the script *"update to whatever is in cell `A1` of the current sheet"*

Sorry if that's too many details. Appreciate any help! One person did post a script which copies any text range to a new range, but doesn't specifically work with formulas. I could pop that in here if it's helpful.

Comment: It looks like the critical part of the formula are the two sections with the day of the month and the month: `20Feb` and `21Feb`  You can use string formulas in JavaScript to concatenate multiple parts of a string.  Then use the `setFormula()` method of a range to insert a formula.  [Apps Script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulaformula)  `txt1 + " " + txt2`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use escape signs in the formula, but then it works fine:

```
var nameReportSheet = "Report";
var targetCellNotationForQuery = "C3";

function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu("Generate Formula")
    .addItem("Generate Formule","generateFormula")
    .addToUi();
}

function generateFormula() {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  var formula = "=query({<DATA>},\"select Col3 where Col2 = '\" & $B3 & \"' \",0)";
  var data = [];
  sheets.forEach(function(sheet) {
    if(!new RegExp(nameReportSheet,"i").test(sheet.getName()))
      data.push("'" + sheet.getName() + "'!$A:$C");
  });
  var newFormula = formula.replace("<DATA>",data.join(";"));
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(nameReportSheet).getRange(targetCellNotationForQuery).setValue(newFormula);
}
```

Comment: This is awesome! So much much streamlined than I even intended!  Thank you SO much! Quick followon if you have a moment, but I may be able to play with it, and will continue to do so:

Is there a way to remove the target cell/sheet and make it so that wherever it sees the ranges, it updates them? It may not be the most efficient way to do it, but in the spreadsheet this is going into I have numerous query functions that differ slightly. I added an example into Column D to illustrate.

Comment: If it can't be done, I'll try to see if I can rework the sheet to need less versions of the script.

Comment: This is possible. If you need only a couple of them, you could copy my script and change the targetCellNotationForQuery for every function (make it a local variable within the function generateFormula and then make copies of this function generateFormula). If you need 10+ of them, it is better to write code!

Comment: Btw, it's probably more convenient to copy the formula and then replace B3 by C3, then D3, etc. (you can do this with javascipt's replace function or even with a text editor)

Comment: Got it - I can make that work for me. Thank you so much, again!